# How can I prevent particular testcase from getting added into pytest_cache lastfailed file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I'm using `pytest --lf` command to rerun the failure one.
When running above command for first time ever I want add only failed testcases into `.pytest_cache/v/cache/lastfailed` file. How can I prevent the the testcase, which is not failed but was facing some error, to add into lastfailed file.

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def useful_fixture():
    raise Exception("Some Error")

def test_one(useful_fixture):
    print("Test case stating")

def test_two():
    assert 5 == 6
```

Currently lastfailed file contain both testcases. `test_two` testcase is failure one so it make sense to rerun it but the `test_one` was facing some error so I want to prevent that testcase entry to lastfailed file. Is there any way?

Comment: why? it certainly didn't pass?

Comment: I have some fixture which setup some configuration before testcase running. If I face any issue in that configuration I'm raising error now my testcase is not failing but there is an error in setup itself. So i want to prevent that testcase rerun.

Comment: but what if the test is also broken, you'd never rerun it properly

Comment: For my case, If the configuration itself is failing I don't want to bother spending time on rerunning testcase. If my fixure is failing I will get reason from my junit-xml file but I don't want to rerun it as I'm sure that rerun can't fix that